# BehaviorSubject always defaulting to false before programmatically being set

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm using BehaviorSubject for authentication in my app, when it's set to true it means the user is logged in with a token and valid expiration and the app should redirect them to the home dashboard page. When it's false, they should be prompted to login.

Everything is working as expected except when the app resumes and the user is logged in. Even though the user is logged in and `BehaviorSubject` is set to true, it will be briefly set to false before checking the token again and then setting it back to true. This results in a brief navigation to `/intro` followed immediately by the proper navigation of `/users/dashboard`

Is there a way I can prevent this glitchy navigation?

authentication.service.ts

```
export class AuthenticationService {
  state = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor(
    private storage: Storage,
    private platform: Platform
  ) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.checkToken();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Ensures the user has access and is not passed their expiration
   */
  checkToken() {
    this.storage.get('token').then(token => {
      if (token) {
        this.storage.get('expiration').then(expiration => {
          const currentDate = moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
          if (moment(currentDate).isBefore(expiration)) {
            this.state.next(true);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
// Authentication
this.auth.state.subscribe(state => {
  alert(state);
  if (state) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
    this.router.navigate(['users', 'dashboard']);
  } else {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
    this.router.navigate(['intro']);
  }
});
```

Comment: If you don't want `BehaviorSubject` to have a default `false` value you can use `ReplaySubject(1)` instead that won't emit until you explicitly call `next()` on it.

Comment: @martin false indicates the user is logged out, which should be the default.

Comment: So you want it to have a default value and to not have a default value at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pipe through `debounceTime` to set a timeframe for which only the latest value will be emitted. Since this change may happen in a tick, 100ms is probably way too much in your case. Consider lowering the time according to your needs:

```
this.auth.state.pipe(debounceTime(100)).subscribe(state => {
  alert(state);
  if (state) {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(true);
    this.router.navigate(['users', 'dashboard']);
  } else {
    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);
    this.router.navigate(['intro']);
  }
});
```

A solution that arguably saves a little bit of time on debouncing would be to use a conditional debounce that only kicks in on `false` values:

```
debounce(state => timer(state ? 0 : 100))
```

Comment: This seems to be working from the quick test I just ran.

Comment: @JoeScotto That's good. I made a little edit to show an alternative that works better in your case. Setting the debounce time conditionally saves you the time you use as debounce time when `true` is emitted. For the debounce time used in my example this makes 100ms.

Comment: Yup, I used 50ms with the conditional debounce... seems to be working perfect. Thanks!